# Minishift on remote machine

Tags: openshift, minishift

I'm trying to 'start' a minishift cluster on a remote machine (not the standard way on a virtualized machine). Both my machines (the control node and the target) reside in AWS, have access to internet but do not have public IP's. The installation passes through but in the end an error is printed:

*'Error during post cluster up configuration: Unable to add sudoer role: The connection to the server 127.0.0.1:8443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port ?'*

The start command is as follows:

*minishift config set vm-driver generic*

*minishift start --remote-ipaddress 10.112.33.85 --remote-ssh-user root --remote-ssh-key path_to_key*

I tested the installation with public IP's and it passed through without any problems. Does it mean that remote machine installation is not supported for non public IP's ? Firewalls on both machines are fully open, the machines can connect via ssh, control node runs RHEL 7, target Centos 7 (RHEL before, makes no difference). I tried the usual delete ~/.minishift and stuff, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Remote machine installation works fine within a private network. The problem was in proxy configuration which is rather tedious.